# Rename files in specific order

Tags: linux, shell-script

I'd like to have a script that renames files (add numbers in front of it) depending in which folder they are.

So I have following scenario:

```
AAAMap
AABMap
AADMap
AAEMap
AAA.map
AAB.map
AAD.map
AAE.map
```

There we have 4 folders and 4 map-files.
First thing to do is to symlink every file into every folder and give them a number, dependong on which relation their INDEX (ascending by name) is to the index of the folder.
So it would look like this:

```
AAAMap
 '- 01_AAA.map
 '- 02_AAB.map
 '- 03_AAD.map
 '- 04_AAE.map
AABMap
 '- 01_AAB.map
 '- 02_AAD.map
 '- 03_AAE.map
 '- 04_AAA.map
AADMap
 '- 01_AAD.map
 '- 02_AAE.map
 '- 03_AAA.map
 '- 04_AAB.map
AAEMap
 '- 01_AAE.map
 '- 02_AAA.map
 '- 03_AAB.map
 '- 04_AAE.map
```

If I re-run the script, it should delete all the symlinks and create them completely new. (Except if you find a better solution with just renaming and reordering the files) -> because there could be files added (each file will get their own folder too) which can be at any position of the file index (alphabetical order).

So for example if we simply add **AACMap** folder and **AAC.map** file.
Numbering inside the folders would be different if this file will get added.

Any idea how to solve this on a elegant way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: We are not a script writing service. Please show us what you have tried to do yourself so far and where you're having trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Cycle through the maps: First loop (auto-sorted) to count and prepare
NUM=0
for MAP in *.map ; do
  ITEM=$(basename "$MAP" '.map')

  # Ensure directory exists and is empty
  DIR="${ITEM}Map"
  mkdir -p "$DIR" || continue
  rm "$DIR"/*.map 2>/dev/null

  # Increase count
  NUM=$(($NUM+1))
done

# Cycle through the maps: Second loop (auto-sorted) calculate number
OFFSET=0
for MAP in *.map ; do
  ITEM=$(basename "$MAP" '.map')

  # Cycle through the maps: Inner loop (auto-sorted) create links
  IDX=0
  for DIR in *.map ; do
    DIR=$(basename "$DIR" '.map')"Map"

    LNK=$(printf "%02d_$ITEM.map" $(((($OFFSET+$NUM+$IDX) % $NUM)+1)))

    # Remove "echo" from next line after testing
    echo ln -s "$MAP" "$DIR/$LNK"
    IDX=$(($IDX-1))

  done
  OFFSET=$(($OFFSET+1))
done
```

Comment: Wow, I must say I'm impressed. That was quite fast and did exactly, what I needed. Thank you very much for this nice script :)